# Padding between columns in CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know if there's a better solution to solve the space problem between the two first columns in this code: https://jsfiddle.net/5vtc1Lhp/#&togetherjs=qkIyJnDkmf

I did try to place div inside div, but the width of the div decreased in the first example ( at the top). At the botton it works fine, but I had to define a padding value in px which I don't like since it's a fixed value and I don't know if this spacement should change automatically.

```
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                                ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                                ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<hr>
Bellow is OK.
<hr>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">

                    <div class="col-md-4 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-8" style="padding: 0 0px 0 30px;">
                        <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                            ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                        ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                    </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: So your final product should be the one which you have shown below, right?

Comment: Right. The last one is the correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Container gives gutter of 30px(15px on left and right)
If you remove the container and give it a row.It will give -15px padding on both sides. And that's what you are looking for, right?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                    ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
                    ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
            ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
            ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 well text-center">
            ...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...<br>...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @lecaro. It does the same as I did in the second example, however, you notice that in your example we have some margin in the right and left of the whole content? It's like there's a padding in class="container-fluid". Do you know how to remove these extra spaces?

Comment: Just edited @lecaro's answer. I guess that's what you are looking for. When he approves edit you will be able to see it. You can see this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vtc1Lhp/3/) though.

Comment: With the new answer (without extra css), it's perfect. Thank you both.

Comment: Perfect Dhaval, that was the point... if you saw Raphael, Dhaval only changed the container-fluid to row

Comment: Yes, I saw that. Now I understand better the div structure, I mean, how it "flows". Thank you again.